# Problem while parsing pixdaus feed

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I am trying to perform parsing of Pixdaus feed at client side using java script.

I am facing following problems:

1. I am unable to perform parsing directly from this url: http://feeds.feedburner.com/PizdausPopularTodayPics
2. So I tried to copy the content and save the file at this location: http://db.tt/5Zq98Kw while doing so I am unable to get content within description tags

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

The sample file which I am using to parse it can be found at: http://db.tt/MyIeYrc

Note: currently it supports parsing on firefox only.

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 1):

Loading XML document from Pixdaus did not work due to 'Cross-domain' issues.

**Extract description**

I would rather extract the description from the document in the following way:

```
var desc = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('description');
for( var i = 0, len = desc.length; i < len; ++i ) { 
   console.log( desc[i].firstChild.nodeValue ); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, for the code :) .. can you suggest me how to resolve this cross-domain issue... I am trying to parse XML obtained from feed, I thought we can do it without any issues!

Comment: There is no direct way of bypassing cross-domain issues in JavaScript unless the browser support 'Cross Origin Resource Sharing' ( server setup is needed for this). I can only think of using a Apache Reverse Proxy, here is an example ( http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/11/making-cross-sub-domain-ajax-xhr-requests-using-mod_proxy-and-iframes/ ). As this XML feed is from FeedBurner, you can also try out Google Feed widget and possibly Google Data API (not sure, do some research on this).

Comment: thanx :) I will definitely check this !